# Similar Value Comparison

Tags: excel-formula, string-comparison

I am trying to figure out a formula that compares the values from one column of a worksheet to find some form of that value in another.

Example

```
 Worksheet #1 (List of values to find)

 Column A

 10935954
 12297606
 M8171210
 MS90728-66


 Worksheet #2 with formula

 Column A                 Column B with Formula Result

 10935954-7               Yes
 12297606-S               Yes
 M8171210-V1345           Yes
 MS90728-66G              Yes
 10935966                 No
 10935954-165             Yes
```

Comment: Ouch, you're right,  I misunderstood the question...my answer is wrong. I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the current example you can do it whit that formula:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$1,A1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$2,A1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$3,A1)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$4,A1)))
```

It is may be not the brightest idea but it works. 
It returns TRUE if value contains in the given values or FALSE if do not.
If you want to be written yes or no you can always do that:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$1,A1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$2,A1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$3,A1)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$4,A1))), "Yes", "No")
```

If you are using Excel 2007 try this:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$1;A1)); ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$2;A1)); ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$3;A1)); ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$4;A1)));"Yes";"No")
```

You have to copy/paste the formula to other cells (A2, A3, A4, A5 and A6)

Comment: This formula is returning values that are not in the search parameters.

Comment: @Todd could you be more specific or give some example

Comment: is there a way I can send you my file?